memcpy後のアドレスが変わっている
直面している問題
Cでコードを書いており、任意のバイト数だけコピーしたいと思い、memcpyを使いました。
しかし、memcpyをした後では自分が指定したアドレスではない値が出てくるようになりました。
知りたいこと
なぜ値が変わってしまうのかが知りたいです。strncpyでは変わらなかったので疑問です。
実際のコード
ソースコードが大きいので、抜粋して載せさせていただきます。

readで相手から受け取ったパケットを処理しているコードです。
パケットの内容はMQTTプロトコルで、connectメッセージ内のRemining lengthを計算するときに、任意のバイトだけエンコード関数に渡すのですが、そのときの任意のバイト列をコピーするときにmemcpyを使うとアドレスがおかしくなります。

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024


void print_bits(const char *label, const unsigned char *data, int length) {
    printf("%s: ", label);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (int j = 7; j >= 0; j--) {
            printf("%d", (data[i] >> j) & 1);
        }
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}


void print_binary(char byte) {
    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%d", (byte >> i) & 1);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

// Dummy client structure for socket file descriptor
struct Client {
    int socket_fd;
};

void *handle_client(void *arg){
    struct Client *client;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int valread;
    char remaining_length_byte[4]; 
    int Packet_Length = 0;
    // Assuming client is already initialized and connected
    print_bits("packet contents", (unsigned char *)buffer, valread);
    while ((valread = read(client->socket_fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0) {
        buffer[valread] = '\0';
        char *p = buffer;
        int remaining_length_byte_count = 0;

        // Determine the number of remaining length bytes
        while (1) {
            if (buffer[remaining_length_byte_count + 1] >> 7 == 1) {
                remaining_length_byte_count++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        printf("before\n");
        print_binary(p[0]);
        print_binary(buffer[0]);
        printf("remaining_length_byte_count %d\n", remaining_length_byte_count);

        memcpy(remaining_length_byte, &buffer[1], buffer[remaining_length_byte_count + 1]);

        printf("after\n");
        print_binary(p[0]);
        print_binary(buffer[0]);

    }

    return;
}

bufferの内容
packet contents: 00010000 00001100 00000000 00000100 01001101 01010001 01010100 01010100 00000100 00000010 00000000 00111100 00000000 00000000 

実行結果
before
00010000
00010000
remaining_length_byte_count 0
after
01010001
01010001


質問文に書かれていない箇所に原因があると思われます。print_binaryは正しく出力するのか。p、buffer、remaining_length_byteはオーバーラップしていないのか、途中で値が変化していないのか。などなどが考えられます。

他の人が回答するために推測など無しに問題を再現・調査出来るような詳細な情報や完結したソースコードを提示するようにしてみてください。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。良い質問をするには？, 再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方

再現する完全なコードがあると理想的ですが、最低限 p buffer remaining_length_byte の型と初期化方法、それらのアドレス、memcpy() 前の buffer[1] の内容、などがあると回答できる可能性が上がります。

@int32_t ,@sayuri,@kunif さん、質問の修正をしました。　ご迷惑をおかけしました。　よろしくお願いします。


memcpy(remaining_length_byte, &buffer[1], buffer[remaining_length_byte_count + 1]);


とのことです。
コピー先となる第１引数はremaining_length_byteが指定されていますが、char remaining_length_byte[4];と定義されており、4バイト分しか確保されていません。
コピーバイト数となる第３引数はbuffer[remaining_length_byte_count + 1]が指定されています。remaining_length_byte_countは0なのでbuffer[1]となります。

packet contents: 00010000 00001100 00000000 00000100 01001101 01010001 01010100 01010100 00000100 00000010 00000000 00111100 00000000 00000000 
                 ^0       ^1       ^2


とのことですので、buffer[1]は12です。4バイトしか確保されていないremaining_length_byteに12バイト書き込むため、バッファオーバーランを引き起こしメモリが破壊されています。
buffer[0]の値が書き換わったのはバッファオーバーランによるものと推測されます。

ありがとうございます。
ただの、引数ミスでした。。。。。
memcpy(remaining_length_byte , &buffer[1] , remaining_length_byte_count+1);
とすると、きちんとできました。。
ありがとうございました。
